# Angularjs-ui-router, ui-view is not working.

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, angular-ui-router

I am writing a angular app.

which contains index page, register page
below written code is of index file.

```
<html data-ng-app="dreamflow" lang="en">

<head>
    <% include ./partials/head %>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <header>
            <% include ./partials/header %>
        </header>
        <div class="ng-animate" ui-view></div>
        <footer>
            <% include ./partials/footer %>
        </footer>
    </div>
    <!-- library after page load-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/browser/controllers/dreamflow.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

This is the code of home page

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row custom-row2">
        <h1>MAIN PAGE</h1> 
    </div>
</div>
```

this is dreamflow.js

```
'use-strict'
angular.module('dreamflow', ['ui.router'])
    .config(['$urlRouterProvider', '$stateProvider',
        function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider) {
            $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
            $stateProvider
                .state('home', {
                    url: '/',
                    templateUrl: '/browser/views/home.html'
                })
                .state('register', {
                    url: '/register',
                    templateUrl: '/browser/views/register.html',
                    controller: 'RegisterController'
                });

        }
    ])
```

This is registerCtrl.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('dreamflow', []);
myApp.controller('RegisterController', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
        $scope.title = "Sign Up";
        $scope.register = function() {
            var user = {
                name: $scope.name,
                email: $scope.email,
                organization: $scope.organization,
                username: $scope.username,
                password: $scope.password
            };

            //Register(user);
        };
    }
]);
```

When we add the registerCtrl.js script in the index file (just below dreamflow.js) then our ui-view doesn't work.

When we didn't use registerCtrl.js in index file then ui-view works fine but RegisterController shows following  error.

**Error: error:areq Bad Argument**

**Argument 'RegisterController' is not**

When we add this registerCtrl.js file anywhere before dreamflow.js then also it shows the same error.

I am unable to find what exactly the problem is. i am trying to solve this from past three days but didn't able to resolve this even after going through all issue related to this error or topic.

Answer (score 0):

In registerCtrl.js, the first line actually instantiate your module again.
what you meant was :

`var myApp = angular.module('dreamflow');`

Also, I don't see a `.run()` on your module, which mean to me that your app is not running.

Comment: The `run` method isn't required.